# What does this icon mean on suggested edits?

Tags: support, suggested-edits

What does the blue icon in the picture below and its value indicate?

[image: too minor with icon]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That means that two other people have rejected the edit with the reason of "too minor".

Answer (score 4):

It means that two other users have voted for that option already.